# Should a local class defined inside a method be thrown as Exception?

Tags: java, exception

It is possible to throw function local class as exception. Is this good or not?

My intention was to explain exception context over exception class type.

```
class A {
    void method1() throws IOException {
        class Method1IOException extends IOException {
        }
        throw new Method1IOException();
    }

    void method2() throws IOException{
        class Method2IOException extends IOException{
        }
        throw new Method2IOException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: I totally don't get you. If you want to throw something, it must extend [Throwable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html). Methods are no objects, so they cannot be thrown, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: @Turing85: Look at the code - the OP is talking about declaring exception classes within a method, and declaring that the method can throw that exception. It all works fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet ah ok, after reading the title again, i get it. The title is somewhat confusing.

Comment: Such a thing could be useful if callers could catch your specific type of exception to distinguish scenarios where your method had an expected kind of IOException from those where it was bubbling up an unexpected kind; for that to work, though, I think your type of exception would need to be public, would it not?  I'd suggest also that while nesting the exception types may make sense, they should likely be `static`.  Otherwise the exception type will contain a hidden reference to the object whose method threw the exception; an okay thing if that reference is useful, but dubious if it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `extends` is a typo for `throws` in your method declarations here.

You cannot throw an `Exception` unknown within that scope, which would be the local scope of your method (vs the instance of your class `A` in this case).

So either your local `Exception`s extend `RuntimeException`, or your `throws` clause must throw a general `Exception` (or `Throwable`).

Anyway, I wouldn't recommend this practice, unless you are never re-using the local `Exception` - and even then...

Context should be expressed programmatically within the message, and automatically within the stack trace, but in this case it will only add some noise to your stack trace.